# What's wrong with my iPhone camera: note the black and pink arcs

Tags: iphone, camera

Any idea what is causing the distortion in the upper left of this photo? The blurry curved black and pink lines?

[image]

Comment: Every photo or just this one?

Comment: Dirt on the lens?

Comment: @SolarMike - unlikely. It's amazing how much damage a lens front element can take & still produce almost viable images. See https://www.lensrentals.com/blog/2008/10/front-element-scratches/ for quite an extreme demonstration from an expert in the field.

Comment: It looks like how the light is hitting the camera lens. I had a similar problem when mine was cracked, but I’m guessing there’s no immediately apparent signs of damage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apple Store evaluated it and concluded that the lens was damaged. No obvious source of damage, they replaced it under warranty.